# How to loop through all files of a specified type in a given directory in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to loop through all files of a certain type in bash. Both, the path to the directory with the files and the file name extension (i.e. file type) should be specified in variables at the beginning of the script:

```
WDIR=/data/test/
FTYPE=".csv"

COUNT=1

for FILE in "${WDIR}"/*"${FTYPE}"; do
    echo "##### Processing file # $COUNT: $FILE ######"

    # DO STH. ELSE

    ((COUNT+=1))
done
```

For some reason unclear to me, this loop fails and seems to treat the statement including the path and file type it should check as a string, producing only one loop that tried to read the file  `/data/test/*.csv` instead of all all .csv files in the directory.

I am a novice and cannot figure out what exactly is wrong, but I suspect that it hast to do with the `"${WDIR}"/*"${FTYPE}"` syntax?

Maybe an expert can spot right a way what I am doing wrong and help me out? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This *should* work, provided there are actually .csv files in that directory. But I see one possible problem: you have a "/" at the end of `$WDIR`, and also add one after it, so the pattern you're expanding is essentially `/data/test//*.csv`. The double-slash *shouldn't* matter (it should be equivalent to a single slash), but it's possible the shell you're using has a bug in this specific case. Does `echo "/data/test/"/*".csv"` give you a list of matching files?

Comment: Thank you, yes it was actually the problem of adding an additional "/" as well as looking for the wrong file type (I only used CSV here as an example). Everything works now; thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you, but if you insist on having the *COUNT*, you have to make a slight change to it:

```sh
WDIR=/data/test/

## create an array containing file names
files=( $(find $WDIR -mindepth 1 -type f -iname "*.csv" | sort ) )

## loop over the files
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
     # YOURCOMMAND
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are no paths that match the globulation, it is not getting modified and just passed along.

```
$ echo *.txt
1.txt 2.txt etc....txt
$ echo *.nonexistentfile
*.nonexistentfile
```

Research bash option `shopt -s nullglob` if you want non-matching glob expand to nothing:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ echo *.nonexistentfile
# nothing is printed out
```

It's typical in a for loop to check if really what you get is really a file:

```
for file in "${wdir}"/*"${ftype}"; do
     if [[ ! -f "$file" ]]; then break; fi
     ....
```

Prefer to use lowercase variables in your scripts.